# how to get the email input already filled when landing on Auth page

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, spotify

When I land the Authorization page of `Spotify` it is possible to have the email input already filled?

Doing something like that:

```
res.redirect('https://accounts.spotify.com/authorize?' +
  querystring.stringify({
    response_type: 'code',
    client_id: client_id,
    scope: scope,
    redirect_uri: redirect_uri,
    state: state,
    email: "myemail@gmail.com"
  }));
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on [the documentation](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/general/guides/authorization-guide/) it's look like you cannot preset the email on their form.
So I would say "No" you can't.